# Why engine instanceof GroovyScriptEngineImpl ?

Tags: groovy, scriptengine, jsr223

in groovy while getting the ScriptEngine using java6 feature, for groovy it gives me instance "GroovyScriptEngineImpl" which a type of class not an interface, is there any other way to get the interface ?

```
ScriptEngineManager  factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");
assert engine instanceof GroovyScriptEngineImpl
```

is there any interface available instaed of using "GroovyScriptEngineImpl"

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is the `ScriptEngine` interface not good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GroovyScriptEngineImpl](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/jsr223/GroovyScriptEngineImpl.html) implements the Compilable, Invocable, and ScriptEngine interfaces.